# Not validating required validation

Tags: 7, forms

drupal_validate_form is not validating required validation when i was creating a node programatically .

Can any one say, it is design like that or am i doing something wrong .

```
        $node_form = (object) array(
            'type' => 'MY_CONTENT_TYPE',
            'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
        );
        $form = drupal_get_form('application_node_form',$node_form);
        $old_fs = @unserialize($r->form_state);
        $form_state = array();
        $form_state['values'] = $old_fs['values'];
        $form_state['values']['op'] = t('Save');
        $form_state['submitted'] = 1;
        $form_state['complete form'] = array();
        $form_state['triggering_element'] = array('#parents'=>array('next'),'#button_type'=>'submit');
        unset($form['#token']);
        drupal_validate_form('MY_CONTENT_TYPE_node_form', $form, $form_state);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the form failed validation by calling [`form_get_errors`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_get_errors/7)

You could try using [`drupal_form_submit`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7) instead, which I think will also validate the form (seen via `form_get_errors`)

Comment: yes but drupal_form_submit check the form validation and after that it will save it if validation have no error.

Comment: oh my goodness what i was trying is a multi step form so if the 1st tab is validate then form is validate